# Changing page size within Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have a very large phylogenetic tree that I'd quite like to insert into a supplementary material I'm writing using Rmarkdown and knitr. I dislike splitting trees across pages and I doubt anybody would print this out anyway so I thought I'd just have a large page in the middle of the pdf I'm generating.

The question is how do I change page size for one page in an otherwise A4 document? I'm pretty new to knitr and I've found global paper size options but I'm struggling to find ways of setting up what would be the equivalent of sections in Word.

(Update) Hi does anybody else have a suggestion? I tried the pdfpages package but this seems to result in an equally small figure on a page the size of the pdf that is being pasted in i.e. if I make a 20in by 20in pdf figure then paste the page in using \includepdf then I get a 20in by 20in page with a much smaller figure on it (the same as the \eject example above). It seems like knitr or Latex is forcing the graphics to have a specific size regardless of page size. Any ideas? Here's a reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
    pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdfpages}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
require(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,
                      warning=FALSE,
                      message=FALSE,
                      dev = 'pdf',
                      fig.align='center')
```

```{r mtcars, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
pdf("myplot.pdf", width=20, height=20)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
dev.off()
```

#Here's some text on a normal page, the following page is bigger but has a tiny figure.

\newpage

\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{myplot.pdf}
````

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `\ejectpage` like this:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

\eject \pdfpagewidth=20in \pdfpageheight=20in
```{r mtcars}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
```
\eject \pdfpagewidth=210mm \pdfpageheight=297mm

Back
````

(I can only remember the A4 height in mm for some reason)

[image]

Comment: Actually having looked at this, even when changing chunk options you can't get the figure to fill the new page size. Now that I know what to search for, it seems that I'm not alone in this...

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306447/draw-with-pstricks-on-a-large-paper-size

I guess I might have to use R to write the figure to an appropriate sized PDF then paste the page in.

Comment: argh! apologies. i thought it would be this easy (i should have known better…this is latex after all).

Comment: @JimmyK, any luck solving this issue?

Comment: @Geoff no luck in the end. I moved on from Rmarkdown following this.

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced the same struggle when dealing with a large phylogenetic tree.

Based on [hrbrmstr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36912607/7247477), I came up with the snippet below.

The trick is to make knitr generate the figure but not include it in the intermediate .tex right away (hence `fig.show="hide"`). Then, because figure paths are predictable, you can insert it with some latex after the code chunk.

However, the new page height is not taken into account when positioning page numbers, so they tend to be printed over your image. I have tried to overcome this behavior multiple times, but in the end I simply turned them off with `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r fig_name, fig.show="hide", fig.height=30, fig.width=7}
plot(1)
```

\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}

\pdfpageheight=33in

\begin{figure}[p]

\caption{This is your caption.}\label{fig:fig_name}

{\centering \includegraphics[height=30in, keepaspectratio]{main_files/figure-latex/fig_name-1} }

\end{figure}

\clearpage

\pdfpageheight=11in
````